# Copyright year is not updated in the error page

Tags: bug, status-planned, design

I accidentally [append some characters](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent/testurl)  with the [Stack Overflow Talent](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent) URL and I received a Oops! page.

In the bottom of the page I see the copy right content as

> © 2016 Stack Exchange, Inc.

Since in most of the places the copyright content's year was updated to 2017. Hope it is not updated in this page.

Comment: Checking with our legal team before taking action on this

Comment: @JonChan Now I can see `© 2017 Stack Exchange, Inc.` in the footer of the Oops! page. Can this be changed to `status-completed`

Answer (score 8):

Actually, the date should *absolutely not* be changed to the current year.  Copyright notices should show the date when the copyright was first registered.

From [copyright.gov](https://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap4.html):

> (b) Form of Notice.—If a notice appears on the copies, it shall
>   consist of the following three elements:
>       (1) the symbol © (the letter C in a circle), or the word “Copyright”, or the abbreviation “Copr.”; and
>       (2) **the year of first publication of the work;** in the case of compilations or derivative works incorporating previously published
>   material, the year date of first publication of the compilation or
>   derivative work is sufficient. [snip]
>       (3) the name of the owner of copyright in the work, or an abbreviation by which the name can be recognized, or a generally known
>   alternative designation of the owner.

It's a common enough mistake, but luckily one that can be fixed by laziness.

Comment: So what's the definition of publish for a web page? If it were a book, a new version being printed would be a new publication with it's own copyright year. If the contents of a page is significantly changed, can/should that be considered a new publication with the year updated? If it's tied to the existence of the page's URL, not its contents, does that mean if a page is simply moved that's enough that it's copyright should be updated?

Comment: @BSMP Not really interested in trading corner cases.  I'm not a lawyer, I've just dealt with this issue recently and had the links.  All your answers can be found on copyright.gov.

Comment: *Not really interested in trading corner cases.* I don't even know what you're talking about here.